# Not able to order member according to the latest chat order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a requirement where I have to order the user from the chat table according to the unread message followed by latest conversation wise.

I have my table structure as follows:

id    |   from_member_id  |  to_member_id   |  added_time  |   message  | is_viewed

Here from_member_id and to_member_id are the primary key of member table. message is the message sent to each other and is_vied is a flag which denote whether message is viewd or not by the receiver or to_member_id. So, I have a member_id now I have to match that with both column but I want the result should be sorted according to unread message first followed by unread message.

I am using this query

```
  SELECT `from_member_id`
       , `to_member_id`
       , MAX(`added_time`) AS latest
       , `is_viewed`
    FROM `wp_doc_profile_message`
   WHERE `from_member_id` = 3
GROUP BY `from_member_id`
ORDER BY `is_viewed` ASC, `latest` DESC
```

It is not giving my desire result. Please help.

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: why using max(added_time) as latest? How many records you get as output?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can match `to_member_id`  with OR operator and  `group by id` message table id so that records were not duplicated

```
SELECT `from_member_id`,`to_member_id`,max(added_time) as latest,`is_viewed` FROM
 wp_doc_profile_message WHERE  from_member_id = 3  OR to_member_id=3 
 group by `id`
 ORDER BY is_viewed ASC, latest DESC
```

OR

```
SELECT pm.`from_member_id`,pm.`to_member_id`,max(pm.added_time) as latest,pm.`is_viewed` FROM
 wp_doc_profile_message  pm
LEFT JOIN members m ON (m.id=pm.`from_member_id` OR m.id=pm.`to_member_id` )

 group by pm.`id`
 ORDER BY pm.is_viewed ASC, latest DESC
```